# How to get running out of space warning earlier?

Tags: compiling

I'm running 12.04 and my file system and /home are both on a rather small 120Gb SSD. They need to be there, because my principal daily activity is compiling phone Roms, and that takes forever if I do that on SATA2 drives. The problem is, compiling takes up a lot of space; I can build 2 Roms comfortably, but then have to do a make clobber (delete the compiling output) in order to start the subsequent builds. Of course, sometimes I forget to do this, get the warning that I'm running out of space, but by then it's too late - the third build had already aborted because the compiler couldn't write the output. The only thing to do in that case is to delete the previous builds and start over from scratch.

Is there any way to make the system warn me about low space when there's, say, 5GBs left, instead of just 1Gb? That way I could have time to get rid of the previous builds before the compiler gives up.

Comment: 1) Do you use the command line terminal to compile? 2) Are the previous outputs required to generate new output?

Comment: 1) yes, there's no other way for now 2) old output is not needed for the new builds, I simply forget to chuck it in the rubbish...old age, you see.

Comment: Rinzwind's method is probably what you wanted. Another tweek that you could do is to write a shell script to do this and then after the line to compile it, you just give a command to delete using rm <filename>!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dash-> dconf-editor and navigate to "house keeping" (exact path is in the image).

[image]

> Command line

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.housekeeping  free-size-gb-no-notify  5
```

and the 1 Gb changes to a 5 Gb.